# How do you load a third-party module in debian-installer?

Tags: debian-installer, preseed

I'm trying to install Debian Bullseye on a new Lenovo laptop (T14s Gen1). The laptop has a Realtek 8852AE wifi chip, for which currently no driver has been added to the kernel. There is [a Github repository](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89) where a suitable driver appears to be present, and I'm able to build both the firmware and the kernel modules on another Debian Bullseye machine.

I have created a Debian Bullseye usb stick and added my regular preseed file, which is working fine. I tried adding a series of 'early_command's, but d-i always throws an error at the first early_command it encounters. Any pointers what is wrong with it?

```
### Copy the Realtek 8852AE firmware during installation
d-i preseed/early_command string \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw8852a_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw8852a_fw.bin;

### Modprobe the Realtek 8852AE network driver during installation
d-i preseed/early_command string \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw89core.ko /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64/rtw89core.ko; \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw89pci.ko /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64/rtw89pci.ko; \
/sbin/depmod -a \
/sbin/modprobe rtw89pci;

### Copy the Realtek 8852AE firmware on target machine
d-i preseed/late_command string \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw8852a_fw.bin /target/lib/firmware/rtw8852a_fw.bin;

### Modprobe the Realtek 8852AE network driver on target machine
d-i preseed/late_command string \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw89core.ko /target/lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64/rtw89core.ko; \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw89pci.ko /target/lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64/rtw89pci.ko; \
/bin/touch /target/etc/modules-load.d/rtw89.conf; \
/bin/echo "rtw89pci" >> /target/etc/modules-load.d/rtw89.conf;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded to get debian-installer to recognize the Realtek 8852AE chipset and load the firmware and kernel modules, so I guess this is the answer to my own question:

```
### Make the Realtek 8852AE firmware available during installation
d-i preseed/early_command string \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw8852a_fw.bin /lib/firmware/rtw8852a_fw.bin

### Make the Realtek 8852AE network driver available during installation
d-i preseed/early_command string \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw89core.ko /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64/rtw89core.ko; \
/bin/cp /cdrom/realtek8852/rtw89pci.ko /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64/rtw89pci.ko
```

My initial attempt failed because at the "preseed/early_command" stage, no other modules have been loaded, and as a result the command to modprobe this module fails because of unmet dependencies.

Mental note: the early_ and late_command's accept multiple commands chained to one another with a colon(;), but make sure that the last command is not followed by such a colon...

Next challenge: actually connecting to the network during installation :/.